# dpkg was interrupted, asked to disable UEFI Secure Boot

Tags: dpkg

I was in the process of downloading a Gdebi package from the software center but the installation seems to be stuck at 0% and not proceeding at all.

Followed by which I tried installing the .deb file from the terminal, this was the message that appeared

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

so I ran the `sudo dpkg --configure -a` command and then this appeared

[image]

Comment: did you set the password ubuntu asked you to ?

Comment: If you are referring to the password asked by Ubuntu before every download then , yes I have.

Comment: ok now restart your system and repair the `dpkg utility` as directed. let me know how it goes!

Comment: I restarted my system, dkpg error still persists.

Comment: should I disable UEFI Secure Boot?

Comment: yes you should do that please and paste the `dpkg` error message!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had problems related to UEFI Secure Boot when installing Ubuntu 16.10.
Try confirm this with pressing Tab -> Enter (the OK button). If the problem remains you may try to disable UEFI Secure Boot on your firmware settings if this gives you such possibility.

Also, when file /var/lib/dpkg/lock exists, make sure there is no active process like apt, apt-get nor dpkg. If you cannot find such process (use ps command with root permissions), try to remove lock file.